# compressing folders with tar and trying to exclude a folder

Tags: tar, archive

I'm trying to get a small script to run smoothly, it's supposed to archive all subfolders under /docker/*.
What I wan't is the script to exclude all folders that has a date (i e 20191010, 20180502 and so on)
this is my tar line:

```
for dir in *
# loop trough folders and archive them
do tar --exclude='//([12]\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))' --warning=no-file-changed -cjf "$dir".tar.bz2 "$dir" # no trailing slash!
    # Move created archive into subfolder
    mv ${dir}.tar.bz{datefolder}
done
```

But what it does is first creates the daily fodler (201909xx), and then it includes that in the tarballs. 
What am I missing?

Clarification (folder structure):

```
~/docker
    20190915  <- this should be excluded
    composer
    watchdog
```

The rest of the subfolders should be archived, each in its on tarball. .tr.bz2

Comment: I don't follow the question. Please expand on the details a bit.

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to exclude the daily created folder (for example 20190915) from the tarballs. If I have the following folder structure;
<code>/docker
  /20190915
  /composer
  /whatever
  /somethingelse</code>

I want tar to exclude the datefolder .

Comment: Updated the original question

Comment: I'm not sure that's a valid glob (admittedly I'm not certain). `tar` accepts glob (`man 7 glob`) expressions, not regex.